# Unmet dependencies error, apt-get -f install does not help

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies

After upgrading from 12 to 14.04 I try to run: sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common

I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libemail-foldertype-perl : Depends: libmodule-pluggable-perl but it is not going to be installed
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                              Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python-apt-common (>= 0.9) but 0.8.3ubuntu7.3 is to be installed
                              Depends: python3-dbus but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.92.37.7) but it is not going to be installed
                              Breaks: python-software-properties (< 0.85) but 0.82.7.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried to run sudo apt-get -f install to resolve, but that gives me this error:

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmodule-pluggable-perl all 5.1-1 [21.2 kB]
Fetched 21.2 kB in 0s (332 kB/s)                      
(Reading database ... 601575 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libmodule-pluggable-perl (from .../libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.1-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man3/Module::Pluggable::Object.3pm.gz', which is also in package securityonion-libmodule-pluggable-perl 5.1-0ubuntu0securityonion1
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?
Thanks,
Nate

Comment: Did you tired to install  just the  _libmodule-pluggable-perl_?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Get the same error as when I run sudo apt-get -f install.

Comment: Did you tired to install it using dpkg after [downloaded it](https://packages.debian.org/sid/perl/libmodule-pluggable-perl)?

Comment: Tried that. I got a slightly different error:  *Unpacking libmodule-pluggable-perl (from libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.2-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.2-1_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/perl5/Module/Pluggable.pm', which is also in package securityonion-libmodule-pluggable-perl 5.1-0ubuntu0securityonion1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.2-1_all.deb*